# What makes this Laravel permissions-checking middleware fail?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-middleware

I am working on a **blogging application in Laravel 8**.

The application gives the users rights by assigning them roles. Every role has a set of permissions. There is a *many-to-many* relationship between roles and permissions.

In the *user-rights* view, I output each user's permissions successfully:

```
 @foreach ($user->role->permissions as $permission)
    <span class="badge bg-primary">{{ $permission->slug }}</span>
 @endforeach
```

#### The goal

I am trying to restrict access to the *Site settings* section of the application, like this:

```
// Settings routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'settings', 'middleware' => ['checkUserPermissions:edit-settings']], function() {
    Route::get('/', [SettingsController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard.settings');
});
```

For this purpose, I have created the **checkUserPermissions** middleware:

```
class CheckUserPermissions
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */

    // Permissions checker
    public function hasPermissionTo($permission) {
        return in_array($permission, Auth::user()->role->permissions->toArray());
    }

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$permissions)
    {
      // Check user permissions
        foreach ($permissions as $permission) {
          if (!$this->hasPermissionTo($permission)) { 
            $permission_label = join(' ',  explode('-', $permission));
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'You do not have permission to ' . $permission_label);
          }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

#### The problem

Although the super admin does have the permission to *edit settings*, `dd(in_array($permission, Auth::user()->role->permissions->toArray()))` returns **false**.

That means that the restriction(s) apply when they should not.

#### NOTE

`dd(Auth::user()->role->permissions->toArray())` returns:

[image]

#### Questions

1. What causes this bug?
2. What is the easiest fix?

Comment: What exactly does `Auth::user()->role->permissions->toArray()` hold? My guess is the `permissions` is actually a collection of models and `$permission` is just a string? This needs debugging details..

Comment: Logged in as an admin, what does `dd(Auth::user()->role->permissions->toArray());` give you? If it's null, try with `->role()->`.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey The authenticated user's permissions.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir you can better post the result of those questions in your original question, best thing is to show dd() then to say: "it's showing this and that"

Comment: @UnderDog I have edited the answer and provided details.

Comment: Still assuming the `$permission` is a string and likely holds the"slug" value, does `Auth::user()->role->permissions->pluck('slug')->toArray()` solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom middleware, you need to compare the permission to the slugs

```
return in_array($permission, Auth::user()->role->permissions()->pluck('slug')->toArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're eager loading `permissions`, Eqloquent will return a collection of models. Inside of the `Collection` instance, there is a `pluck` method that will create a new collection of columns.

Using the `toArray` method, you will then end up with the expected array that your `$permission` will match to:

```
Auth::user()->role->permissions->pluck('slug')->toArray()
```

An alternative way would be to use PHP native methods (`array_column`) to achieve this. You could then return a list back to the view of all of the missing permissions as apposed to a single missing permission. This is untested but should just work out the box:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, ...$permissionsToTest)
{

    $permissions = array_column(Auth::user()->role->permissions->toArray(), 'slug');

    $results = array_map(fn(string $permission): bool => in_array($permission, $permissions), $permissionsToTest);
    $failedResults = array_keys(array_filter($results, fn(bool $result): bool => !$result));
    $missingPermissions = array_map(fn(int $key): string => 'You do not have permission to ' . implode(' ', explode('-', $permissionsToTest[$key])), $failedResults);

    # Utilise the built-in "errors"
    return empty($missingPermissions) ? $next($request) : redirect()->back()->with('errors', $missingPermissions);
}
```

For a vanilla PHP mock-up example, [See it 100% working over at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/F6p1T)

Comment: using `->permissions()->pluck('slug')` relation method instead of `->permissions->pluck('slug')` attribute fetch will not load a collection of the model instances of the Permission class.